# How to change color in mat-icon when it click in Angular material

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

I am using Angular 6 when i click the mat-icon  i want to change the color of that icon so please help me to do this.

```
 <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Add to wishlist" (click)="addToWishList(product)"><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon></button>
```

Comment: You can simply add a CSS class to it dynamically. Have a look at [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) which adds and removes CSS classes on an HTML element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 NgClass change css class which is in the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51320357/angular-6-ngclass-change-css-class-which-is-in-the-tag)